# Flutter & Dart : Carousel with videos

Tags: flutter, dart, video, carousel, flutter-dependencies

Flutter & Dart : How to stack multiple videos in a Carousel Widget?

I am trying to stack a multiple videos in a Carousel Widget but I am only getting one(1) video since I just provide one video link in the VideoPlayerController.network.(). Is it possible to use a ArrayList of String or is there any best and easiest way to do it?

```
  Future<void> initializePlayer() async {

    videoPlayerController =    VideoPlayerController.network('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/WhatCarCanYouGetForAGrand.mp4');
    await Future.wait([videoPlayerController.initialize()]);
    chewieController=ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
      materialProgressColors: 
      ChewieProgressColors(
        playedColor: Colors.red,
        handleColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        bufferedColor: Colors.grey
      ),
      placeholder: Container(color: Colors.black),
      autoInitialize: true,
    );
    update();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Take `Listview` widget and implement below code in link

[Carousel in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65175807/how-to-play-a-list-of-video-carousel)

Comment: Can you please explain how I can use that code? I am new to Flutter. Thank you